# Criar um formato de avaliação em PHP (Ratings) Dinâmico

Tags: php

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
Pessoal,estou criando um portal de música e gostaria de criar um script igual ao da foto acima em PHP. Meu objetivo é analisar CD's lançados e postar notas referente as a características do CD vou analisar.

Estou sem ideia de como fazer o mesmo,agradeço qualquer ajuda.
Obrigado

Comment: amplo demais
Ou há muitas respostas possíveis ou boas respostas seriam muito longas para este formato. Acrescente detalhes para reduzir o conjunto de respostas ou isole uma questão que possa ser respondida em poucos parágrafos.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Em seu banco de dados você deve criar 2 campos, um para armazenar a quantidade de votos e outro para acumular a quantidade de pontos.

Como o valor máximo da nota é 5, então na seguinte situação:

200 votos a pontuação máxima será 1000; 201 votos serão 1005 e assim por diante;

Ex.:

> ## CD 1 - recebeu 2 votos
>
> Voto 1 = 5.0
>
> Voto 2 = 4.2
>
> Nota final **4,6**
>
> ## CD 2 - recebeu 3 votos
>
> Voto 1 = 5.0
>
> Voto 2 = 4.2
>
> Voto 3 = 1.5
>
> Nota final **3,5**

Para fazer os cálculos

> Nota final: Pontuação total / Quantidade de votos

A inserção dos pontos deve possuir uma condicional, os valores devem estar entre 0 e 5.

Com essa lógica acredito que você irá conseguir desenvolver as etapas.

Caso queira um script pronto e queira adaptar ao seu sistema [clique aqui](http://www.script-tutorials.com/how-to-create-own-voting-system/), mas seria interessante você mesmo tentar fazer para aprendizado próprio.